# Mixed Mode Authentication (SQLMembershipProvider )in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, forms-authentication, mixed-authentication

I'm new to TFS 2010 (Team Foundation Server 2010) and I'm looking forward to authenticate users in TFS using Mixed Mode Authentication.  I mean using Windows Mode Authentication and SQL Authentication with SQLMembershipProvider and SQLRoleProvider.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Gonzalo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The users that you add to the authorization of TFS, are not the users in SQL Server.

The user that is accessing the database is the service account of TFS.

Comment: So I can only add Active Directory users to Team Foundation Server Team Projects?

Comment: You can add windows users. So that could also be users in a workgroup

Comment: So, I can't use My SqlMembershipProvider nor SqlRoleProvider?

Comment: No, but what do you want to achieve?